# initialize struct array element with different value using memset in c++

Tags: c++, struct, initialization, memset

In C++,

```
struct info
{
    int lazy,sum;
}tree[4*mx];
```

Initialize :

```
memset(tree,0,sizeof(tree))
```

That means

```
tree[0].sum is 0 and tree[0].lazy is 0 ...and so on.
```

Now I want to initialize different value like this:

```
tree[0].sum is 0 and tree[0].lazy is -1 .... and so on.
```

In For loop

```
for(int i=0;i<n;i++) // where n is array size
{
    tree[i].sum=0;
    tree[i].lazy=-1;
}
```

but in memset function I can't initialize structure array with different value. is it possible ??

Comment: Nope, not possible with a single call to memset. Use [`std::fill`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/fill).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To [`memset`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/memset/) you pass value that every byte of a given address range is initialized with.

> memset - Sets the first num bytes of the block of memory pointed by ptr to the
>   specified **value (interpreted as an unsigned char).**

As such, you cannot achieve what you want.

This is what a *constructor* is for:

```
struct info
{
    int lazy,sum;
    info() : lazy(-1), sum(0) {}
} tree[4*mx];

// no need to call memset
```

Or you can create a pattern of the struct and set it to every element of your `tree`:

```
#include <algorithm>

struct info
{
    int lazy,sum;
} tree[4];

info pattern;
pattern.lazy = -1;
pattern.sum = 0;

std::fill_n(tree, sizeof(tree)/sizeof(*tree), pattern);
```